# Answer got edited but it does't show edited beneath that answer

Tags: discussion, support

I replied to an answer on Stack Overflow and edited my own answer, and now it shows below edited 2 mins ago. But another person also replayed that particular question with forEach loop first, after few minutes they changed their code to `if` statement inside another loop and deletes that `forEach` loop. But their answer doesn't show the edited beneath his answer. I can't figure out why and how?